# Not able to deploy kubernetes resources with terraform in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy Kubernetes resource(Secrets) in AWS EKS using Terraform. Here is my resource looks like

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.34"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.15.0"
    }
  }
}


data "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {
  name = "shared_eks01"
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "this" {
  name = "shared_eks01"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.this.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.this.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.this.token
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "spacelift" {
  metadata {
    name      = "spacelift123"
    namespace = "spacelift"
  }
  data = {
    "token"              = "123"
  }
}
```

I am unable to deploy the resource and I am getting this below error

```
kubernetes_secret.spacelift: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Post "https://6FC8A63F36709AA...........gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/spacelift/secrets": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
│
│   with kubernetes_secret.spacelift,
│   on main.tf line 63, in resource "kubernetes_secret" "spacelift":
│   63: resource "kubernetes_secret" "spacelift" {
```

Also tried Adding **load_config_file = false** in provider results in

```
An argument named "load_config_file" is not expected here.
```

Can you pls tell me what am I missing?

Comment: There is no `load_config_file` in `kubernetes_secret` according to the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/secret). Not sure why would you expect it to be there?

Comment: @Marcin that i tried using in provider. Not in secret

Comment: The error is about `"kubernetes_secret" "spacelift"`. Its quite confusing what did you actually do.

Comment: The end goal is to deploy secret in eks cluster in a particular namesapce  using terraform

Comment: Did you run `terraform plan` prior to running apply?

Comment: terraform plan says 1 to add (kubernetes_secret.spacelift)